# how to refresh comoponents inside tab in extjs4?

Tags: extjs, tabs, refresh, extjs4

for my application that im developing with extjs4 and c#, im basing on the [browser-layout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)  example.
so i have a menu on the left side and tabs, in each tab i call my components (grids,trees,charts..)

now i need to refresh some or all of the components in the tab when i click on it

how can i do this?

i use a listener on a tab like this :

```
listeners: { activate: function () {
                              alert('tab1');
                          }
```

but i have two problems:

**1-** how do i actually refresh a componenet like charts grid or tree ?
i know i can use `getCmp(chart1)` to access my component but then i dont know what to do to refresh the data displayed

**2-** as i said im based on the browser layout example, so i have a left menu,then on clicking on each item of that menu i have on the right  side all my tabs
now the listener im using on the tabs only work when i do click on the tab, but doesnt work when i select from left menu except first time, to be more clear, when i first load my application, i have to select an item from left menu,then it shows my tab with tab1 activated,now everyting works good,but if i select another item then go back to my tab,it doesnt work!!

here is the code called on menu click:

```
    menuPanel.getSelectionModel().on('select', function (selModel, record) {
        if (record.get('leaf')) {
            Ext.getCmp('content-panel').layout.setActiveItem(record.getId() + '-panel');
            Ext.getCmp('dash-tabpanel').setActiveTab(0);//getActiveTab()//if (record.getId() = 'dash')
}}
```

thanks in advance for ur help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`tabchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-tabchange) event:

```
myTabPanel.on('tabchange', function(me, newCard, oldCard){
  // newCard is newly activated item of tab.Panel. You can refresh it or manage it as you like here
});
```

UPDATE

Regarding your updated question:

Where is actual `tab.Panel`?

If you add `tab.Panel` with `id:'tab1'`:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    id: 'tab1',
    items: [
        {title: 'first tab', html: 'dkjgkdkgjk'},
        Ext.create('Ext.app.myGauge')
        ]
});
```

and if you move `Ext.getCmp('tab1').on('tabchange', ...` to the end (so that it would be called after panel is created) then your example should work. [Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/J46sw/).

Comment: excuse me i still very new to extjs..where do i put this? and how do i actually refresh the components?

Comment: @astrocybernaute, first of all, tell what do you mean by 'refresh'?

Comment: in my application,data is related, so in one tab a user can add data or modify that displayed in an other tab, so i want to refresh that data from database so it shows the most recent one. hope im clear enough.excuse my english

Comment: @astrocybernaute, it depends on what data is in your tabs. For example if there is grid you can refresh data by calling `grid.store.load()`. Here I've mage [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KEV5h/2/) to play arround with(Needed code at the bottom).

Comment: in my layout-browser i call my panels.. with  `Ext.create('Ext.app.myGrid') `  , in myGrid.js i have  : `definitions of store` then `Ext.define('Ext.app.myGrid', {..creating my grid..} `  i tried use ur suggestion, but i get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined**   i'll edit my question with an example

Comment: as i said in my question ,im basing on the layout-browser example so my tab is [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layouts/basic.js) i will try to do as u said but im not sure..will let  u know.thanks

Comment: @astrocybernaute, Oh, I see. You are assigning handler to wrong component. You have to assign it to `tab.Panel` not to a item of `tab.Panel`. In your case your `tab.Panel` has id `card-tabs-panel`. So try assign handler to it by using `Ext.getCmp('card-tabs-panel').on('tabchange', ...`.

Comment: i added the code at the end after the return (see the earlier link ) . i didt get an error but nothing happened, also in ur code in jsfiddle when i change the id:'tab1' and put it in 'first tab' (cause this is how i want it to work,refresh on each tab click not on the whole tabpanel ) nothing happens either

Comment: even though its not what i need to do (see my previous comment) i tried it and nothing happens either

Comment: i posted it again since i didnt get a helpful answer,accepted ur just to close this, thank you for ur time

Answer (score 3):

create model and refer in store like following way instead of JsonStore.

```
Ext.define("Post", {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url : 'yourURL',

           method:'GET',

           reader: {
               type: 'json',
               root: 'rows'
               //,totalProperty: 'totalCount'
           }
               //,autoLoad:false
       },

       fields: [
           {name: 'docid', mapping: 'docid'},

       ]
   });

      var gridDataStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         // pageSize: 10,
          //autoLoad:false,
         // border:false,
         // frame:false,
          model: 'Post'
      });
```

now use gridDataStore.load();
this will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh which is updated from database.

```
DataStoreName.load();
Ext.getCmp('id').doLayout();
```

here id means the id of control which you want to refresh.

Comment: Extjs  Store have load() method, and it is working fine with my code. You can check on http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store

Comment: this is how i call it : `Ext.getCmp('myGauge').load();` and it at each time it says no method, is it because i use getCmp ? or is it because of the store type? i have 'Ext.data.JsonStore'

Comment: I have added another answer for you. check it.